# How to add shadow for animating circular uiview in ios objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**I tried below code :**

```
View.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
View.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
View.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0, 10.0);
View.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:View.bounds cornerRadius:100.0].CGPath;
```

but its not working.

Many thanks.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it crash? (where's the log?) Does it not look right? (where's the screenshot?) Does your phone melt when you try to run it? Does Xcode crash? Explain what "not working" means.

Comment: did you set masksToBounds to your view ?

Comment: check that view is not overlapping on shadow. OR Try to share more code

Comment: @Fogmeister not getting the shadow.

Comment: @vishnuvarthan I set masksToBounds.
View.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

Comment: So describe what IS happening in the question. Not just "not working" that is no help to anyone.

Comment: shadow is an effect done outside the View, and that masksToBounds set to YES will tell the UIView not to draw anything that is outside itself. So set it to NO.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am really sorry,

Comment: @JijinSundar don't be sorry. Just update the question to include a description of what is happening. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
View.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
View.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0, 10.0);
View.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
View.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method and change it to UIView if you need:

```
-(UIImageView *)changeViewToShadow:(UIImageView *)newImageView withIcon:(UIImage *)image
{
    newImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    newImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    newImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    newImageView.layer.cornerRadius = newImageView.frame.size.height/2;
    newImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    newImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    newImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
    return newImageView;
}
```